# Using mongose aggregation to populate from collection in mongo

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework, mongodb-aggregation

**Sample document**

```
{
     _id:"123",
     "completed" : [ 
         {
             "Id" : ObjectId("57caae00b2c40dd21ba089be")
             "subName" : "oiyt",
             "Name" : "Endo",

         }, 
         {
             "Id" : ObjectId("57caae00b2c40dd21ba089be"),
             "subName" : "oiyt",
             "Name" : "Endo",
         }
    ] 
}
```

How do I access the `name` and `subname` from `complete` where `_id` matches?

Comment: Access via mongoose? Have you defined the mongoose schema? It should just be single call after defining the schema model. Somethings like:

`MyModel.find({"_id": "57caae00b2c40dd21ba089be"}).exec(function(err, docs){
 if(!err){
  console.log(docs[0].completed.Name);
  console.log(docs[0].completed.subName);
 }
});`

Comment: while find i need to fetch the only name and subname not whole doc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `$filter` or `$unwind`  (or both).

This example shows how to use `$filter` to get the document only with one matched element in the array, and then `$unwind` to get easier access to the matched element.

but there are many more options to get the desired result.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $project: {
            filtered_completed: {
                $filter:{
                    input: "$completed",
                    as: "complete",
                    cond: {
                        $eq: [input_id, "$$complete.Id"]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $unwind: "$filtered_completed"
        // because we already filtered the 'completed' array, we will get only one document.
        // but you can use it as the first aggreagation pipeline stage and match the _id
    },
    {
        $project: {
            "filtered_completed.Name": 1,
            "filtered_completed.subName": 1
        }
    }
])
```

read more about [$filter](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) and [$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/)

Comment: yes it matches my requirement ..but can we use $in cond for the multiple id's

Comment: yes, as I wrote, this is only an example out of many options.